# Unexpected behavior with AWS Firewall and Default Stateful Rules

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, firewall, cloud, aws-vpc

I have configured an AWS Firewall in our testing account, pretty much following the standard setup procedure as documented by AWS. From our private subnet, outbound traffic heading to the internet is directed towards the firewall subnet, where we have another route table directing traffic through the firewall and out to the NAT gateway. The NAT gateway exists in the public subnet and within that subnet there is a route that permits outbound traffic to the internet out via the internet gateway. Within the firewall, the stateless default rule for all packets is to direct them to the stateful rule groups. There are no other stateless rule groups. As for the stateful rule groups, there is one domain list rule group supposedly allowing traffic to ".google.com". The default rule is set to drop established connections.

Here is the problem I am facing, whenever I enable the default rule of "drop established" it continues to permit all traffic through the firewall. It doesn't appear to actually take any effect nor drop any traffic to other domains. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Welcome, Thomas. Can you please edit your question to be more precise - "AWS Firewall" is not specific. Do you mean AWS Network Firewall, security groups, or something else? Please also add a diagram to help people understand your network.